# Calling Javascript Function from ascx

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

From the HTML section of my ascx file, how can I call a JavaScript function?

`<div>  <% if(foo(...)) %>

  // callJavaScriptFunction() ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the code is only run once its in the browser so there isnt any way to get an answer.

You need to approach the problem from a different direction.

Either move the JavaScript code into server side code, post the information you need back in a form so its there on the server side when you need it, or use a web service to run the server side code from the JavaScript code.

What problem are you trying to solve?